# StringBuilder used with PadLeft/Right OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, string-concatenation

All, I have the following `Append` which I am performing when I am producing a single line for a fixed text file

```
formattedLine.Append(this.reversePadding ?
                     strData.PadLeft(this.maximumLength) :
                     strData.PadRight(this.maximumLength));
```

This particular exception happens on the `PadLeft()` where `this.maximumLength = 1,073,741,823` [a field length of an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` gathered from SQL Server]. `formattedLine = "101102AA-1"` at the time of exception so why is this happening. I should have a maximum allowed length of `2,147,483,647`?

*I am wondering if https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769472/626442 be the answer here - however, I am managing any memory with the appropriate `Dispose()` calls on any disposable objects and `using` block where possible.*

Note. This fixed text export is being done on a background thread.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your title and your body are out of sync - you claim that it's `Append` which is throwing in the title, but then in the body you say it's `PadLeft`. I strongly suspect that `Append` is irrelevant here.

Comment: Agreed. I will change this now...

Comment: calling `Dispose` on objects does not invoke the garbage collector.  fyi.

Comment: @recursive I know. I understand this and no where here have I suggested it does. Thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This particular exception happens on the PadLeft() where this.maximumLength = 1,073,741,823

Right. So you're trying to create a string with over a billion characters in.

That's not going to work, and I *very* much doubt that it's what you really want to do.

Note that each `char` in .NET is two bytes, and *also* strings in .NET are null-terminated... and have some other fields beyond the data (the length, for one). That means you'd need at least 2147483652 bytes + object overhead, which pushes you over the 2GB-per-object limit.

If you're running on a 64-bit version of Windows, in .NET 4.5, there's a special app.config setting of [`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) that allows arrays bigger than 2GB. However, I don't believe that will change your particular use case:

> Using this element in your application configuration file enables arrays that are larger than 2 GB in size, but does not change other limits on object size or array size:
>
> - The maximum number of elements in an array is UInt32MaxValue.
> - The maximum index in any single dimension is 2,147,483,591 (0x7FFFFFC7) for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures, and 2,146,435,071 (0X7FEFFFFF) for other types.
> - The maximum size for strings and other non-array objects is unchanged.

What would you want to do with such a string after creating it, anyway?

Comment: That should probably be a comment, not an answer.  Also, he states a belief that he should have a 2G address space, so dealing with 1G is quite possibly what he has in mind.

Comment: Regarding your edit... why do you require a special app.config setting to allocate such large arrays under 64-bit .NET implementations?

Comment: @EricJ.: Not sure why it's only an option, to be honest.

Comment: Hi Jon. You are right in the fact that I don't particularly want to pad the fixed text field with that length but I am currently writting a utility to export ANY database table. This feild is nText and its max length is gathered automatically. Perhaps I need to look at restricting this max length. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @EricJ.: I don't see anything about a 2G address space - have I missed a comment somewhere here? Anyway, I hope you now think my answer is more than a comment :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, your answer has grown up nicely :-)  The OP states `I should have a maximum allowed length of 2,147,483,647`

Comment: @EricJ.: Right, but that could just refer to `String.Length` being a signed int, for example. It's not clear from the post where the OP believes the limitation would come from.

Answer (score 2):

In order to allocate memory for this operation, the OS must find *contiguous* memory that is large enough to perform the operation.

Memory fragmentation can cause that to be impossible, especially when using a 32-bit .NET implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have thought about this cause. But I am managing any disposible objects seemingly well. Is calling the GC a viable option here or is this merky water? Thanks for your time...

Comment: @Killercam: Try doing this with Visual Studio's memory profiler.  You will see what is happening with memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a better approach to what you are trying to accomplish. Presumably, this `StringBuilder` is going to be written to a file (that's what it sounds like from your description), and apparently, you are also potentially dealing with large (huge) database records.

You might consider a streaming approach, that wont require allocating such a huge block of memory.
To accomplish this you might investigate the following:

The `SqlDataReader` class exposes a `GetChars()` method, that allows you to read a chunk of a single large record.
Then, instead of using a `StringBuilder`, perhaps using a `StreamWriter` ( or some other `TextWriter` derived class) to write each chunk to the output.
This will only require having one buffer-full of the record in your application's memory space at one time. Good luck!

Comment: This is a good answer an is essentailly what I am doing. I am using an SqlReader to read a single row (I could trim this down to a single field in a row). I have found that the problem comes with the default padding applied to fields such a `NTEXT` which can be large (1,073,741,823). I think I just need to handle the default padding in a more reserved fashion... Thanks for your time.