# StringBuilder out of memory

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to crash-test my parser with the following string:

```
var theWholeUTF8 = new StringBuilder();
for (char code = Char.MinValue; code <= Char.MaxValue; code++)
{
        theWholeUTF8.Append(code);
}
```

However, the test crashes itself while building the string and throws OutOfMemoryException.
What am I missing?

Comment: Read this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769447/interesting-outofmemoryexception-with-stringbuilder

Comment: `theWholeUTF8` isn’t really an accurate variable name; UTF-8 is an encoding, and .NET strings use UTF-16.

Comment: Also, that string won't actually be valid UTF-16. And it won't contain all Unicode code points.

Comment: @MikeRoll Because of [surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is tha `code` overflows and returns to `0` after being `Char.MaxValue`. The `for` cycle then doesn't end.

Try

```
var theWholeUTF8 = new StringBuilder();

for (int code = Char.MinValue; code <= Char.MaxValue; code++)
{
    theWholeUTF8.Append((char)code);
}
```

To make it clear... At a certain point

```
code = Char.MaxValue - 1

code++; // code == Char.MaxValue
is code <= Char.MaxValue? Yes
theWholeUTF8.Append((char)code);

code++; // code == 0
is code <= Char.MaxValue? Yes
theWholeUTF8.Append((char)code);

and so on!
```

One possible solution is to use for the `code` a bigger variable. Another solution is:

```
for (char code = Char.MinValue; code < Char.MaxValue; code++)
{
    theWholeUTF8.Append(code);
}

theWholeUTF8.Append(Char.MaxValue);
```

where we stop when `code == Char.MaxValue` and we add manually the `Char.MaxValue` .

Other solution, obtained by moving the check BEFORE the addition:

```
char code = Char.MinValue;

while (true)
{
    theWholeUTF8.Append(code);

    if (code == Char.MaxValue)
    {
        break;
    }

    code++;
}
```

Comment: Aha that's it! Or use `char < Char.MaxValue` instead of `char <= Char.MaxValue`. It can never be greater than its max value :)

Comment: @AlexMDC But the he would lose the Char.MaxValue "value" and he would have to add it manually.

Comment: Good point. That's important if you are trying to "crash-test" a piece of code.